# 1970s story about time slip using a potion to slow metabolism

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

In the story, set in the late 19th/early 20th.century, the subject built an underground bunker, with periscopes for viewing the world, and jars of preserved food. He used a potion to slow his metabolism so that he stayed alive for thousands of years. Eventually he was forced to leave his "house" due to earthquake or something, in the future and became a living statue in a future world. I would love to read it again. Does anyone know the title or author?

Comment: I'd swear I've seen this one before... will keep looking.